# Android WebView doesn't change orientation when rotating the device

Tags: android, webview, orientation, local, assets

I want to enable orientation when rotating the device. Normally this happens automatically but in this locally sourced webview, it doesn't happen. It loads in portrait but I would like it to change the orientation depending on how the device is tilted.

I have in the /assets folder adjectives.html

```
// In Activity

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView wv = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(wv);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/adjectives.html");

}


// In manifest
    <activity android:name=".WebViewActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">    
    </activity>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check if rotation is enabled on device ?

Comment: Thanks. It's a bit embarrassing but for some reason, it got turned off. Just by switching it back on, solved the issue!

Comment: I added it as an answer so that people reading can see later what actually happened

Comment: Can you mark it as a correct answer so that people would know how it was solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `android:configChanges` then the specific changes aren't handled for you automatically and you must handle them yourself.

To do this, you must override `onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)` and check `newConfig` to see what the new `Configuration` is. If the change is related to orientation, you'll need to set a new content view.

The easiest thing would be to remove `orientation` from `android:configChanges` (unless you have a particular reason not to) and put your `WebView` inside a layout XML file and use that for your content view in `onCreate(...)`. This will allow the default 'automatic' handling of changes in orientation.

Comment: Thanks for the summary. I understand the design principles behind the android:configChanges now. However issue resolved. The rotation must have got disabled on the device. Enabling it and I got automatic rotation, which I want, even though I have configChanges="orientation"!

Comment: I understand how it works now. As a default, orientation is automatic. If you wish to control the orientation (off,on,do other things) on a device tilt, then you need to add android:configChanges="orientation" in the manifest and override onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig). The method will get executed on a device tilt (if you have set configChanges="orientation in the manifest) and you can code whatever you want to happen. Obviously if you dont code anything the default behaviour of automatic orientation will action.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if rotation is enabled on device ?